# Read timeout error when creating a user c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have this really strange error that appears when Creating / Editing users.
The error looks like this:

> Error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallStreams.InputStream'.

The error in fiddler is:

```
{
  "message": "An error has occurred.",
  "exceptionMessage": "Error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallStreams.InputStream'.",
  "exceptionType": "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException",
  "stackTrace": "   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeDictionary(JsonWriter writer, IDictionary values, JsonDictionaryContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeDictionary(JsonWriter writer, IDictionary values, JsonDictionaryContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.<BufferResponseContentAsync>d__13.MoveNext()",
  "innerException": {
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "Timeouts are not supported on this stream.",
    "exceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "stackTrace": "   at System.IO.Stream.get_ReadTimeout()\r\n   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallStreams.DelegatingStream.get_ReadTimeout()\r\n   at GetReadTimeout(Object )\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)"
  }
}
```

I have tried to figure out what is causing it, but I just can't find the issue.
Here is my Create function:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a user
/// </summary>
/// <param name="model">The bound user model</param>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateUser(UserBindingModel model)
{

    // Save our user to the database
    return Ok(await Save(model));
}

/// <summary>
/// Used to save a user
/// </summary>
/// <param name="model">The model representing the user</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private async Task<IHttpActionResult> Save(UserBindingModel model)
{

    // If our ModelState is invalid, return a bad request
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    // Get the current userId and date
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var date = DateTime.UtcNow;

    // Assign our binding model to a new model
    var user = new User()
    {
        CompanyId = model.CompanyId,
        UserName = model.Email,
        Email = model.Email,
        FirstName = model.FirstName,
        LastName = model.LastName,
        LastLoginDate = date,
        Telephone = model.Telephone,

        CreatedById = string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CreatedById) ? userId : model.CreatedById,
        DateCreated = string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CreatedById) ? date : model.DateCreated,
        ModifiedById = userId,
        DateModified = date
    };

    // Create our result
    var result = new IdentityResult();

    // If we don't have a created by id
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CreatedById))
    {

        // Try to create the user
        result = await this.UserService.CreateAsync(user);

        // Send our the confirmation email
        await SendConfirmationEmail(user.Id);
    }
    else // Else
    {

        // Try to update the user
        result = await this.UserService.UpdateAsync(user);
    }

    // If the creation fails, return the error
    if (!result.Succeeded)
        return GetErrorResult(result);

    // Return the result
    return Ok(this.ModelFactory.Create(user));
}

/// <summary>
/// Used to send a confirmation email to the user specified
/// </summary>
/// <param name="userId">The id of the user we wish to send an email to</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private async Task SendConfirmationEmail(string userId)
{            
    // Generate our unique code
    var code = await this.UserService.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userId);

    // Create the callback url
    var callbackUrl = new Uri(Url.Link("ConfirmEmailRoute", new { userId = userId, code = code }).Replace("api/users", "#/account"));

    // Send the email
    await this.UserService.SendEmailAsync(userId, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
}
```

Has anyone had this error before or know what is causing it?
I have googled this and all the errors seem to be tied to the UserManager which is strange, but no one has any answers.

Comment: We have just experienced this error. It happend when we tried to serialize an asynchronous Task. This happend in our logging mechanism, which logs all in- and out paramters.

Comment: I have found a similar error when attempting to serialize an object which contained streams. It looks like it's to do with the way the objects are being serialized internally. Sorry I can't provide more help than that, but my error was in a rather different domain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This generally occurs when you're "double wrapping", or nesting, the result before finally returning through Web API, the exception you're seeing is JSON serialization hitting an unsupported property of the inner result.

To fix this, review all your methods that are returning `IHttpActionResult`.  I'm confused why you included `CreateUser` method in your code as it doesn't appear to be used by your `Save` method, which is initially what I suspected to be your issue.  If you **had** called `CreateUser` inside your `Save` method and tried to return the result of it, you'd be double wrapping.

Comment: Ahhh, but CreateUser **does** call Save which also returns an IHttpActionResult. So that is the issue, the Create method should return `await Save(model);`